# RestTemplate to elasticsearch 6.7.0 search -> Bad request

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, resttemplate

I trying to access to elasticsearch 6.7.0

(I can't use elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client because I already use it version 7.1.0, I am reaching 2 elasticsearch with different version )

so I build it with RestTemplate

but I am getting a 400 error

```
 {"error":
   {"root_cause": 
 [{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body or source     parameter is  required"}],
 "type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body or source parameter     is required"},
"status":400}
}
```

this what I tried

```java
protected void findByRest(String identification) throws Exception {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search/template";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);


        String json = "{\"source\":{\"size\":\"2000\",\"query\":{\"match\":{\"identification\":\"123456789\"}}}}";

        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(json, headers);

        try {
            ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Object.class);
        }catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            LOG.error("{}",e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw w;
        }
    }
```

this is working fine wiht curl

```sh
curl -X GET \
  http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search/template \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: 127.0.0.1:9200' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 7d1e98f4-23ba-437b-95a7-ea8df9fac837,079e18f5-aaee-4b19-802b-ef4337eaf8c5' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-length: 80' \
  -d '{"source":{"size":"2000","query":{"match":{"identificacion":"132465789"}}}}'
```

any clue ?

Comment: First: What happens if you use POST instead of GET? Second: your query is wrong, you need to unwrap it from `source`, it must start with `{\"size\"...`

Comment: cool ! POST do the trick ! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[`source` is supposed to be a query string parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string), not a section in your query DSL. But you should be able to send that query without sending it in the query string, which is a bad practice anyway.

The way I do it is like this and it works pretty well (i.e. use POST instead of GET since you're sending a payload)

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity(payload.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()), headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestEntity, String.class);
```